# How to do model validation for list in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have controller in Web API which is accepting a list of my model class. I need to validate it before processing for DB request. I know how to do it for single model but stuck on list of model.
Below is my code for it.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateMultiple(List<Employee> employees)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid || employees.Count < 1 )
                {
                     return BadRequest();
                }
}
```

Comment: Manually... you do it either in the handler or you can inject your custom validator. And do for each

Comment: @T.S. can you please help with sample code for reference.

Comment: search "c# validate model manually using validator"

Answer (score 1):

See the added condition check (note that you must change the *yourIndividualValidator* for the actual one)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateMultiple(List<Employee> employees)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid || employees.Count < 1 || 
    employees.Any(x => yourIndividualValidator(x) == false)
     )
     {
         return BadRequest();
     }
}
```